# KeywordQuery Syntax: column contains "abc" OR column contains "xyz"?

Tags: 2013, search, keywordquery, syntax

What is the syntax for column contains "abc" OR column contains "xyz"?

Here is my query:

> *
>       Category:Castle Black OR Category:Kings Landing

Separately "Castle Black" returns 4 results, and "Kings Landing" returns 1 result. But together it is only returning the 1 "Kings Landing" result.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Here it is:

.* Category:"Castle Black" Category:"Kings Landing"

Below info is from [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx)

> When you use multiple instances of the same property restriction, matches are based on the union of the property restrictions in the KQL query. Matches would include content items authored by John Smith or Jane Smith, as follows:
>
> author:"John Smith" author:"Jane Smith"
>
> This functionally is the same as using the OR Boolean operator, as
>   follows:
>
> author:"John Smith" OR author:"Jane Smith"
>
> When you use different property restrictions, matches are based on an
>   intersection of the property restrictions in the KQL query, as
>   follows:
>
> author:"John Smith" filetype:docx
>
> Matches would include Microsoft Word documents authored by John Smith.
>   This is the same as using the AND Boolean operator, as follows:
>
> author:"John Smith" AND filetype:docx

Comment: I think it should be Category:Castle Black" OR Category:"Kings Landing" your syntax is ANDed by default.

Comment: updated my answer to include syntax rules i found on msdn. This seems to be working good for me.